# Proc Freq for values that doesn't exist.

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with column Color. I have values Black White Red in this column. When I trying to count Freq for table column, I have results for black, white and red. But I need else to show zero freq for Green and Blue. How can I do it, if I have no this two colors in the column Color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS Proc Freq display categories with counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301001/sas-proc-freq-display-categories-with-counts)

Comment: Thank's so much! problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be to use `PROC MEANS`, as shown below:

```
proc format;
  value colors 1 = "Black"
               2 = "White"
               3 = "Red"
               4 = "Green"
               5 = "Blue";
run;

data mytable;
  input color;
  format color colors.;
  datalines;
1
2
1
3
;

proc means data=myTable completetypes;
   class color / preloadfmt;
run;
```

[image: Results from proc means]

---

Another way to do it would be to use `PROC TABULATE`, specifying an additional input table (`classdata` parameter) containing all possible values, as shown below:

```
data allColors;
  input color;
  format color colors.;
  datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;

proc tabulate data=mytable classdata = allColors;
  class color;
  table color / misstext = "0";
run;
```

Results:

[image: Proc Tabulate Results]

Answer (score -1):

Use the *missing* option:

```
MISSING
treats missing values as a valid nonmissing level for all TABLES variables. 
Displays missing levels in frequency and crosstabulation tables and includes 
them in computations of percentages and statistics.
```

Also see: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_sect016.htm

Comment: If there are no value in column it won't appear, missing specified or not. If available in other groups can use sparse option to display.